# Does default OpenGL perspective projection matrix preserve straight lines in all three dimension?

Tags: opengl, linear-algebra, projection

I know that the default OpenGL perspective projection matrix preserves straight lines at least in XY - so if three points are colinear in eye-space, the XY coordinates of the three points in NDC will also lie on a straight line - but what about XYZ in NDC? Will the XYZ coordinates of the projected points still be colinear (I'm asking because to me it currently looks like they're not, but I might be wrong)

If not, is there a way to change the projection matrix so that the post-projection points will have this property?

Comment: @KaiBurjack including the Z coordinate?

Comment: @KaiBurjack: Out of curiosity, do you know where to find a mathematical proof for this?

Comment: @KaiBurjack that's not really a proper reason though - because even if the Z coordinates would 'bend' nonlinearly, you would not see that in the final rendering

Comment: @Rabbid76 From my math courses I also remember that projection preserves collinearity (even with the perspective divide). I just couldn't find a proof for it (and trying out some combinations doesn't really count here). There is a sentence [here](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first) which hints on the fact (but no proof given).

Comment: "(I'm asking because to me it currently looks like they're not, but I might be wrong)" What exactly makes you think it isn't? Actually, lots of GPU z buffer optimizations require this (i.e. hierarchical Z).

Comment: @derhass these optimizations just require that Z_eye -> Z_ndc is monotonic, i.e. that Z_eye_1 > Z_eye_2 <==> Z_ndc_1 > Z_ndc_2, they don't require linearity

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann: nope. GPUs Z stage always _linearly_ interpolate the per-fragment z value from the 3 window space z values of the 3 vertices (it's also specified as such in the GL spec). Hierachical Z is an early Z variant which is directly tied into the rasterizer, and for each tile covered by the primitive , it needs to calculate the min/max z value of this primitive in the tile, which is also implemented based on the assumption that the primitive is actually flat.

Comment: @derhass yes of course - I'm not talking abou the fragment interpolation. I'm saying that these optimizations just require that if one position is further away along Z in eye space, it also has to be further away in NDC. It does not require though that there's a linear relationship between eye-Z and NDC-Z

Comment: "It does not require though that there's a linear relationship between eye-Z and NDC-Z " Now you're talking two different things. YOur question was about the projection matrix (in combination with the perspective divide) will presever colinearity - it does. But this does **not** imply that there is a linear relationship between `z_eye` and `z_ndc` - it is not, it's hyperbolic, you'll in general to the form `z_ndc = A + B / z_eye` with `A` and `B` being derived from the  2 non-zero constants in the third row of the projection matrix.

Comment: However, the non-linear relationship there doesn't imply that tha colinearity of line segments is lost (ther eis also a non-linear relationship in the x and y dimension to match that). However, my point about earlier was that the hardware simply linearly interpolates the post-divided z value for depth test and hierachical depth test.  If the colinearity were not preserved, this would  go completely wrong. The only wat to get a "bend" primitive int the z dimension would be to adjust this in the frag shater, completely disabling lots of the earlzy Z HW optimizations which do rely on linearity.

Comment: Maybe [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/derhass/miscstuff/master/OpenGL/img/ztransform.png) will make things clear. All is top-down view onto xz-plane of some frustom. The 'hyperblolisch' one is the hyperbolic default case, and the right one is with a linear relationship between `z_eye` and `z_ndc` - and this is also why HW preferes the flat primitives.

Comment: Now if you ask for an actual proof of colinearity. It shouldn't be hard to do. For sake of simplicity, you can assume that for an Point `P=(p_x,p_y,p_z)` , the projected point will be `P'=(p_x/p_z, p_y/p_z, c/p_z)` ( all other stuff in the proj matrix are actually affine transformations which can be factored out and can be proven to keep co-linearity). Then, for two arbitrary points `A` and `B` and the center point `S = 1/2*A+  1/2* B`, you only need to show that `S' = (1-t) * A' + t * B'. And you can find that `t'` as a non-linear function of the steepness in the z-direction of the line.

Answer (score 0):

#### Proof by geometric argument

For any line `L`, there is a plane `S` that contains all the points in `L` and the origin `O`.

Any line connecting a point `P` in `L` and the origin is also contained in `S`. So the projection will be in the intersection between the plane `S` and the plane `z=1`, and that's a straight line.

#### Using equations

Usually the projection will map `(x, y, z)` to `(x / z, y / z)`, for the camera at the origin, pointing to `z` direction.

Consider the parametric equation of the straight line being `(a * t + cx, b* t + cy, c*t + cz)`, the derivative of the curve in 3D will be
`(a,b,c)`, in the 2D space you have

`dx/dt = ((c*t+cz)*a-(a*t+cx)*c)/((c*t+cz)^2) = (cz*a-cx*c)/z^2`

`dy/dt = ((c*t+cz)*a-(b*t+cy)*c)/((c*t+cz)^2) = (cz*a-cy*c)/z^2`

If you divide `(dx/dt)/(dy/dt) = (cz*a-cx*c) / (cz*a-cy*c)`.

This will draw a curve that with tangent to a constant direction, a.k.a straight line.